# Why my bootstrap boxs are not perfectly sized?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make bootstrap based image gallery. I saved images with 400px/400px (4 of them), 800px/400px (just one) and 400px/800px (just one). Here is how it suppose to look like: [image] 
But my question is why there is space in the bottom of 2 columns?
Here is my code:
css

```
.nopadding {
   padding: 0 !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
}
```

html

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 30px; background-color: grey; ">
    <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 " style="padding: 5px !important;">
                    <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="" width="100%">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 " style="padding: 5px !important;">
                    <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="" width="100%">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 " style="padding: 5px !important;">
                    <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="" width="100%">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 " style="padding: 5px !important;">
                    <img src="images/4.jpg" alt=""  width="100%">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 nopadding">
                    <div class="">
                        <div class="col-md-12 " style="padding: 5px !important;">
                            <img src="images/5.jpg" alt="" width="100%">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 " style="padding: 5px !important;">
                            <img src="images/6.jpg" alt="" width="100%">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mind posting a working example with your problem? Also it seems like you're missing a row class under `<div class="col-md-6 nopadding">` but that might just be a copy paste problem?

Comment: because the height of the 3 boxes on the left are `400px + 400px + {{ the margin between them }}`, so the other columns need to be `800px + {{ that margin value }}`

Comment: The paddings are not accounted for in the images. You'll need to make a few larger, as can be seen [**here**](https://www.bootply.com/4Xte3guBb3). Also note that you're nesting `rows` incorrectly from a BootStrap standpoint; each `row` should have a total of 12 `columns`, and thus, using padding / margin overrides shouldn't be necessary at all.